# How to make a website to move/rotate a 3d shoe model by user and change its color in realtime

Tags: 3d, web

It's a shoe store users will see the shoe from moving/rotating in realtime plus they can also change its color/texture by selecting them.

Which software/language tool should I choose?

I know:

- 3D software: Maya, 3ds Max
- Programming: HTML5 - CSS3 - JS - jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You almost have everything you need. Head over to http://threejs.org/, and start learning how to bring your 3d assets into your browser :)

Basically, for presenting your 3D assets in the browser, you need to tap into the browser's graphical API which is provided by WebGL.

WebGL itself is pretty hard to learn, so better start directly with ThreeJS.

ThreeJS is a light JS library that neatly encapsulates complex WebGL routines into something much more usable, and easier to understand.

There is also Babylon.js, which is very similar to Three.js. I personally prefer ThreeJS, I feel it's more popular, and you can get support if you're stuck.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanksssssssssssssssssssss alot :)